# Interpretar <br /> en una celda de gridView

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

Tengo que separar por marcas de `\n` el contenido de una celda de `GridView` para conseguir que en una celda aparezcan lineas diferentes.

El código en el que me hallo es el siguiente:

*Modificando la `DataTable`:*

```
cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.CommandText = comando;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string text = dt.Rows[i]["OBSFX"].ToString();
    text = text.Replace("\n", " <br /> ");
    dt.Rows[i]["OBSFX"] = text;
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Ahora modificando el `GridView` directamente:

```
cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.CommandText = comando;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[16].Text;
    text = text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
    GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[16].Text = text;
}

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Ninguna de las dos maneras funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. El texto de la `Cell[16]` contiene un caracter de nueva linea y quieres substituirlo por `<br/>`? El código te da algun error o simplemente no hace lo esperado?

Comment: No hace lo esperado o me muestera los `<br/>` en texto plano directamente. No me da ningun error, pero directamente no Hace lo esperado. He estado mirando y hay que cambiar el HTMLEncode a false, pero como el Comando SQL va variando segun las Variables de la Request, no puedo hacerlo mediante clicks en la GridView, y eso me genera el problema de que no hayo la manera de hacerlo mediante codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontre la respuesta a mi problema. Tenia que generar un evento de `RowDataBound`y ahi insertar el siguiente codigo :

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            string encoded = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;  //
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = encoded.Replace("\n", "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Este evento se encuentra dentro de la `GridView`y solo hay que añadir el evento y el codigo y ya funciona solo.
Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra colavoracion!!! :D
Espero que a alguien le ayude.

Answer (score 0):

El método `Replace` sustituye todas las ocurrencias que coincidan con el primer parámetro por el valor del segundo. En tu caso, si quieres cambiar `<br />` por `\n` la instrucción sería:

```
text = text.Replace("<br />", "\n");
```

Justo al contrario de como lo tienes.

Además, para que la celda muestre más de una línea, es posible que tengas que ajustar un par de propiedades en el `GridView`, como el alto de fila automático y el ajuste de palabras (`wordwrap`) en las celdas.